# Using Provider and changes are not reflecting in other widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Hi I am quite new to flutter, and just learned about the Provider package. I want to be able to update my selectionSet (the ingredients the user has selected). I update it in two ways -- through typing in a textfieldsearch and through taking a picture. The picture returns a list of predicted ingredients. The textfieldsearch works,  but the image does not update the selectionSet across widgets. It is returning the correct list, and the selectionSet is updated within the DisplayPictureScreen, but the selectionSet in IngredientsInput is unchanged.

**main.dart -- I have also tried wrapping with ChangeNotifierProvider.value**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => IngredientSelection(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
        home: TossUp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**ingredient_selection.dart**

```
class IngredientSelection extends ChangeNotifier {
  Set<String> selectionSet = {}; 
  void add(String ingredient) {
    selectionSet.add(ingredient); 
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addAll(List<String> ingredients) {
    selectionSet.addAll(ingredients);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**display_picture_screen.dart -- part of interest is in the elevated button**

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.picture});

  final XFile picture;
  final IngredientsClassifier classifier = IngredientsClassifier();
   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Preview Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
          children: [
            Image.file(File(picture.path), fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 250),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (
                () async {
                  var ingredientSelection = context.read<IngredientSelection>();
                  List<String> ingredients = await classifier.getPicIngredients(picture);
                  ingredientSelection.addAll(ingredients);
                  print("After: ${ingredientSelection.selectionSet}"); //returns correctly
                  
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.pop(context); 
                  }
              ), 
              child: Text("get ingredients")
            )
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ingredients_input.dart -- I have also tried to wrap viewSelections return with Consumer**

```
class IngredientsInput extends StatefulWidget {
  IngredientsInput({super.key});
  @override
  State<IngredientsInput> createState() {
    return _IngredientsInput();
  }
}

class _IngredientsInput extends State<IngredientsInput> {
  //...other code 

  Widget viewSelections() {
        IngredientSelection ingredientSelection;
        ingredientSelection = Provider.of<IngredientSelection>(context);
        //var ingredientSelection = context.watch<IngredientSelection>();
        print(ingredientSelection.selectionSet);
        if(ingredientSelection.selectionSet.isNotEmpty) {
          return Container(
                height: 400,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: ingredientSelection.selectionSet.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          ingredientSelection.selectionSet.elementAt(i),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),

                          ),
                      )
                    );
                  }
                ),
              );
        }
        return SizedBox(height: 400,);
      }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
          TextFieldSearch(
            initialList: _ingredientsList, 
            label: label, 
            controller: myController,
            
          ),
          Consumer(
            builder: (context, ingredientSelection, child)  {
                return viewSelections();
            } 
          )
          
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

I have tried to play around with consumers and provider.of and context.read/watch. All of them have the same result: Un-updated set in IngredientsInput, yet updated set in DisplayPictureScreen

Answer (score 0):

Inside `viewSelections()`, notice how you're taking the `context` of the `State` rather than the `Consumer`.

```dart
Widget viewSelections() {
  IngredientSelection ingredientSelection;
  ingredientSelection = Provider.of<IngredientSelection>(context); // <--
```

In fact, the `context` from your `Consumer` is not being used at all.

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ingredientSelection, child)  { // <-- context not being used
      return viewSelections();
  } 
)
```

You should move the code inside `viewSelections()` to the `Consumer`'s `builder`, so the provider will take the `context` from the `Consumer`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really think about how I just left a consumer there with not much else. However, my program is unfortunately still running the same as before.

Comment: Have you tried using context.watch?

Comment: Yes I have and it's the same result

Comment: Hi thank you, with the combination of your answer and deleting a different instance of  my model (not shown in the code I provided as I thought it was irrelevant), I have resolved the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Currently  ingredientSelection is not listening for changes so it can’t update.

Change

```
 ingredientSelection = Provider.of<IngredientSelection>(context);
```

to

```
 ingredientSelection = Provider.of<IngredientSelection>(context, listen : true);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but it doesn't seem to make a difference..

Answer (score 0):

Hi so it turns out that it was an issue in an entirely different block of code. I was having ChangeNotiferProvider in two different places -- on my ingredientsScreen (which is where IngredientsInput is being called) and in my main. So it was creating two different instances of IngredientSelection. Which is why my ingredientsInput was not listening to the changes, it was in a different instance.

Along with that, I was not using context or ingredientSelection in my Consumer. Which was pointed out by Dhafin Rayhan